# Fedora20 not turning on

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I installed Fedora20. After I turn On my system, it says "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has ocurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator".
I re-installed Fedora-20 again, but the problem still persists.
Please guide me through the steps of getting it solved.

Comment: I have has this problem before. There are run levels during Fedora start up (I assume ur in level 5) Bring it to run level 1 (single user mode). From there you can run your diagnostics (`dmesg |all`). This will give you the info on what could have gone wrong. Should this question not be migrated from stackoverflow to _Unix&Linux_ forum. Just asking....

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you get one of the Fedora 20 Live ISO images, burn it onto a CD and run Fedora 20 by booting from the CD.  That way, since nothing is installed or run from the hard drive:

- If the CD fails to boot, or fails to run, then you will know there is probably a hardware problem
- If the CD runs OK, you can perform an install from the running image on the CD

I've had problems in the past with a full install failing, and a subsequent install from a Fedora Live CD working perfectly.  (The XFCE Spin is at https://spins.fedoraproject.org/xfce/)